# How to 301 redirect asp page to another domain using web.config file

Tags: windows, redirect, asp-classic, web-config

How to redirect asp page (http://www.example.com/page.asp?id=11) to another domain (http://www.anothersite.com) using web.config file. I used below code but not working.

```
<configuration><location path="http://www.example.com/page.asp?id=11"><system.webServer><httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.anothersite.com" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" /></system.webServer></location></configuration>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better doing this using URLRewrite or adding some suitable logic to Custom Error page handling.

Have a look at the answers to this question [Configuring custom ASP 404 page with redirect for IIS7 website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016933/configuring-custom-asp-404-page-with-redirect-for-iis7-website/6017627#6017627)