# Send a Response.Status = "404 Not Found" but let IIS remain on the same page

Tags: iis, asp-classic, web-config, http-status-code-404, iis-8.5

I have a simple question:

Is possible to send the Response.Status = "404 Not Found" from a .asp page, but continue to render the actual page?

Seems that when i send Response.Status = "404 Not Found" IIS moves to the default 404 error page, while i would like to continue to render my page. This is a case of a CMS where for some reason someone can type a unexistent permalink and want to display a "OPS not found content page" instead to redirect to a custom or default 404 asp page.

there is a specific web.config setup?

I've followed discussion here:
[Configuring custom ASP 404 page with redirect for IIS7 website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016933/configuring-custom-asp-404-page-with-redirect-for-iis7-website)

And thought to use then option

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

But for some reason it gave me error 500.
The IIS version is 8.5 asp 3.0 / .NET 3.5

my actual web.config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly"/>  

<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" />      
<caching enabled="true">
    <profiles>              
      <add extension=".gif" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
      <add extension=".png" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
      <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
      <add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
      <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
      <add extension=".jpeg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="0.00:01:00" location="Any" />
    </profiles>
</caching>  

<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".js" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript" />
    <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
    <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
    <remove fileExtension=".otf"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="font/ttf" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/x-woff2" />      
    <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>        

<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to friendly URL">
              <match url="^site/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="/default.asp?pl={R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Thank in advance for any solution :)

**EDIT:**

After many test i found the solution:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
```

The 500 error i get if i add the line separate from the "DetailedLocalOnly" is now solved using a one line with both param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is only a typo in your web.config. If above is your configuration file, you forgot to enter the `system.webServer` tag level.

I tested this on IIS 8.5 and it worked as expected. So the ASP generated 
content was shown while the page returned a 404 status code. I really only used following configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Alternatively, but not recommended, it also worked with following configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For the interested, here is the link to the [documentation](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors).

Comment: hi, yes i forgot to paste the top and bottom of the web.config:

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
      ....
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: i've added the line as you said but i get error 500 :(

Comment: edit: i checked that if present <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly"/> anwith passThrogugh it give me 500 error.

Comment: 500 error is a server error, either the web.config file is invalid or there is an error in your ASP file. Turn on "detailed errors" to analyze this.

Comment: no there is no error in my asp files at all. I found the solution to add one line only with both commands. I've Edited my first post just in case someone have the same problem.

Comment: OK, so the web.config was invalid. For other request, please consider giving the whole information in your question. It would have been obvious if you had included both lines with "httpErrors"...

Comment: the <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly"/>  line was already included. If i add an extra line as you suggested was the problem make the config invalid. the solution to join both parameter in one line was the solution. Thank to your suggestion i googled and find out the solution :) ty