# Angular 2 is not redirecting to 404 page when route param and address are invalid

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am developing an application using `Angular 4.1.1`. *I've always declared routing in a module and I do it in* **all modules**.

For example, `new-cars.routing.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { NewCarsComponent} from './new-cars.component';
import { NewCarsResolver } from './new-cars.resolver';    

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: 'cars/:id',
                component: NewCarsComponent,
                resolve: {
                    card: NewCarsResolver
                }
            }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class NewCarsRoutingModule { }
```

I declared this route in `app-routing.module.ts` for incorrect routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And it handles properly wrong addresses, if I write the following addresses in a such format:

```
http://foowebsite/#/sdf /*the address exists*/
```

However, the following addresses are wrong and they are just redirected to home page, but I would like to show `404 page`:

```
http://foowebsite/#/news/-5  /*There is no such route param "-5".Redirecting to home page, but I want to show 404 error*/

http://foowebsite/sdf  /*There is no "sdf" component/module routing. Redirecting to home 
page, but I want to show 404 error*/
```

What I've tried:

```
export const routes: Routes = [  
  { path: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

and:

```
export const routes: Routes = [  
  { path: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' }
];
```

However, invalid urls are just redirected to home page. Please, pay attention, that I'm using module routing to route in modules and application routing to redirect to 404 page.

My `app.module.ts` file:

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        AppRoutingModule        
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent
        ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My `web.config` of ASP.NET Core Web Application looks like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404" 
                                                responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404" 
                                                responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" path="/404" 
                                                responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

**The error page does not occur even I intentionally return `404` error**:

```
[HttpGet("{name}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string name)
{
    return StatusCode(404);
}
```

**What should I write to redirect to 404 page?**

Comment: path: '**' should not have component: '404', it should redirectTo: '404'

Comment: Are you importing your routes const exported in app-routing.module.ts into your main app module?

Comment: In your app.routing.module.ts you need to import the RouterModule and do .forRoot(routes), then export RouterModule which will be imported by app.module.ts. You can do .forChild in your separate components but I don't see those 404 routes being imported anywhere from what you are showing.

Comment: Yeah that looks correct. I'm going to try to replicate your issue in a bit. Will get back to you soon.

Comment: Ok so apparently this could have to do with your web server setup. What web server are you using and do you have a redirect configured to route to your app 404 route?

Comment: You'll need to configure it to redirect to either your index.html or /404 on a 404 error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016933/configuring-custom-asp-404-page-with-redirect-for-iis7-website

Comment: I'm using a tomcat server and this is what I needed to do, you need to capture the 404 error from the server and show your own. Just give it a try and see if that works.

Comment: @Yeysides it is strange, but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
{path: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
{path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}
```